# Call a method from an anchor tag on a ASPX Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to call my code behind method on click of hyperlink on my ASPX design page.

So that I can Fetch the Identity value and pass it to my stored procedure and redirect user to the landing page.

I am facing syntax issue as what to write where.

In my expected code I tried to add runat server but getting error.

Other things are working fine.

**Current Code**

```
    <div class="row">
    <% foreach (System.Data.DataRow item in dt.Rows)
     {  
        %>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 mix livefeeds News">
                    <div class="work-item">
                        <div class="image-holder">
                            <a href="<%=item["Identity"].ToString()%>">
                                <img src="<%=item["ImagePath"].ToString()%>"/>
                                <h4>
                                    <span><%=item["Headline"].ToString()%></span>
                                    </h4>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
         </div>
    <%
    }   
    %>
</div>
```

Expected Code

```
            <div class="row">
    <% foreach (System.Data.DataRow item in dt.Rows)
     {  
        %>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 mix livefeeds News">
                    <div class="work-item">
                        <div class="image-holder">
                       <a href="<%=item["Identity"].ToString() runat="server" onServerClick="MyFuncion_Click"%>">


                                <img src="<%=item["ImagePath"].ToString()%>"/>
                                <h4>
                                    <span><%=item["Headline"].ToString()%></span>
                                    </h4>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
         </div>


    <%
    }   
    %>
</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you use `LinkButton`?

Comment: Same Syntax errors,can you please show me how.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `<% %>` and quotes are messed up a bit. Tired to correct it:

```
<a href='<%=item["Identity"].ToString()%>' runat="server" onServerClick="MyFuncion_Click">
```

However I have doubts this will actually work the way you expect (do a postback straight away) unless you have some javascript handling client onclick.

Comment: red line in below tags,you can copy paste my Current code on your ASPX page and modify it and then you can see the red lines.

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve <a href="images/gallery/1.jpg" id="hrefLiveFeedsOne" runat="server" onserverclick="LiveFeedsOneEvent"></a> but want only one method as the Id will come in it and will pass it to stored procedure and then will redirect it to another page.