# Retain Value on editing drop down on Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Want to reduce my logic on View data from drop down won't come from data base.
Current code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyViewModel.Value,
                                new List<SelectListItem> {
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "1",Value = "1" },
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" },
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "3", Value = "3" },
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "4", Value = "4" },
                                new SelectListItem { Text = "5", Value = "5" },         
                             });
```

Trying to achieve

```
 <select id="MyViewModel.name" name="MyViewModel.name">
                            <option value="">--Select--</option>
                            @for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                            {
                                <option value="@i">@i</option>
                            }
                        </select>
```

On submitting the form I am getting the selected value in my ViewModel i.e action but on editing am not the selected value Like

```
<select data-val="true" id="ddl" name="">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
**<option selected="selected" value="3">3</option>**
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you want to use database values or want to use like this?

Comment: No connection with data base.Hard coded.want to save hit to DB and values wont change.

Comment: still not clear what you wanting to get

Comment: You need to set the value of property in the GET method before you pass the model to the view. `model.MyViewModel.Value = 3; return View(model);` (but its no clear what your model property is - `MyViewModel.Value` or `MyViewModel.name` or `SelectedShowCharacter.as_order`?).

Comment: Its MyViewModel.name Selecte... by mistakely I pasted.

Comment: And why in the world would you want to create the html manually in a for loop?

Comment: M getting the record in Get  model.Class = db.Table.Find(id);

Comment: And you can reduce it down to `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.yourProperty, new SelectList(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }))`, but generating the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` belongs in the controller, not the view

Comment: We want to display few numeric records in drop down and they wont ever change hence saving a data base hit.

Comment: So your suggesting that using for loop not a good idea here.

Comment: Too late (comments can only be edited for 5 min)

Comment: No worries, so using for loop is a bad idea here.

Comment: In order to get proper 2-way model binding using a `for` loop, you will need to add about 50 extra lines of code that the `DropDownListFor()` method takes care of for you (and you can see the [source code here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs)

Comment: As if now @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.yourProperty, new SelectList(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })) works fine.Thank you.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke can you help me with this post please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38265120/call-a-method-from-an-anchor-tag-on-a-aspx-page

Comment: Not today (about to sign off - will take a look tomorrow)

Comment: @StephenMuecke no problem.

Comment: @StephenMuecke You can post your answer @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.yourProperty, new SelectList(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }))  will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118689/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-dave).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code for generating the `SelectList` can be simplified to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.yourProperty, new SelectList(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }))
```

However, that code belongs in the controller, not the view, and ideally you should have a view model with property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, for example

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "...."]
    [Display(Name = "....")]
    public int? SelectedItem { get; set; } // nullable to protect against under-posting attacks
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

and in the GET method

```
MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel
{
    Options = new SelectList(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })
};
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem, Model.Options, "Please select")
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be best to define the data at the control level than in Razor

so create and edit actions will return a list which will be used in DropDownListFor

but Edit will also set the selected value